# Environment and scope when using parallel functions

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing, scope

I have the following function:

```
f1<-function(x){
  iih_data<-...stuff...
  ...more stuff...

  cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 6))
  clusterExport(cl, c("iih_data"))
  clusterEvalQ(cl, require(lme4))

  Tstar<-parCapply(cl, ystar, function(x){
     ostar=glmer(x ~ GENO + RACE + (1|GROUP), family="binomial",data=iih_data,nAGQ=1)
     fixef(ostar)[2]/sqrt(vcov(ostar)[2,2])
  })

  stopCluster(cl)

  ...more stuff...
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'iih_data' not found
```

I am guessing it has to do with the fact that I am trying to run parallel apply inside of a function. Can you guys help me sort this out? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've figured out, `clusterExport` looks for the specified variables in `.GlobalEnv` unless directed otherwise with the `envir` argument.  But in your particular example, `iih_data` is being serialized along with the unnamed function that you're executing with `parCapply`, so the copy that you're exporting to the workers via `clusterExport` won't actually be used.  In fact, all of the local variables that are defined in `f1` before `parCapply` is executed will be serialized along with the unnamed worker function and sent to each of the workers.

This technique can be very useful for sending data to the workers (it's actually used by `clusterExport` itself), but you have to know what you're doing, otherwise it can significantly hurt your performance, especially when using `clusterApply` and `clusterApplyLB`, since they don't do the same *prescheduling* done by `parLapply` and `parCapply`.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates this:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
f1 <- function() {
  iih_data <- 'foo'
  parLapply(cl, 1:3, function(i) iih_data)
}
f1()
```

You'd think that you would get an error saying "object 'iih_data' is not found" since you haven't explicitly exported it, but you don't.  The odd thing is that this doesn't happen when the function is defined from the global environment, because the global environment is never serialized along with functions.

If you think that's strange, things get stranger when dealing with arguments.  Consider this example:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makePSOCKcluster(3)
f1 <- function(iih_data) {
  parLapply(cl, 1:3, function(i) iih_data)
}
x <- 'foo'
f1(x)
```

Given my previous example, you might think that this would work, but instead you get the following error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'x' not found
```

But why does it say "object 'x' not found" rather than "object 'iih_data' not found"?  This is due to R's lazy evaluation of function arguments.  The function and its associated environment is serialized and sent to the workers without ever evaluating the argument "iih_data".  It's not evaluated until the unnamed worker function is executed on the workers, and that's when it discovers that "x" is not defined in the global environment of the workers.

You can fix this by changing `f1` to:

```
f1 <- function(iih_data) {
  force(iih_data)
  parLapply(cl, 1:3, function(i) iih_data)
}
```

If instead of calling `force` you executed `clusterExport(cl, 'iih_data', envir=environment())`, it would work, but not because you've exported it to the workers.  It would work because the argument had been forced, but in a much less efficient way, and the values copied to the global environment of the workers would still not be used.  The worker function would still actually use the copy of "iih_data" that was in the local environment that was created by calling `f1` that was serialized along with the unnamed worker function.

This may seem like an academic issue, but it comes up in various forms once you start to call parallel functions such as `parLapply` and `clusterApply` from inside functions in order to execute unnamed worker functions.  I've been bitten many times by this kind of problem.

Comment: Wow, what an excellent and thorough answer! Thank you! I knew something complicated was going on.

Comment: @Benjamin I included the stuff about unevaluated function arguments because that was an issue that you ran into in a previous question that was perhaps incorrectly marked as a duplicate.  The moral is: "Beware of executing closures in parallel".

Comment: Man, I wish I could make a reproducible example of the issue I'm currently having. I'm 1000% convinced that this is the case, but I don't know how I can reproduce it. I've got a sourced script that has two `cl <- makeCluster(n) parLapply(...some code...) stopCluster(n)` within the sourced script. When the parallel sections happen, a memory leak forms and fills up system memory. I can't reproduce it when I run the contents of the script directly

Answer (score 6):

Adding

```
envir=environment()
```

to clusterExport() fixed the problem. e.g.

```
clusterExport(cl, c("iih_data"),envir=environment())
```