# Performance of clusterApply deteriorates when called inside a function

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I've come across a strange issue with `clusterApply`, which I've been able to isolate as best as I can as follows.  First, I run the following code from the global environement:

```
require(parallel)
cl<-makeCluster(rep("localhost",20),"SOCK")
xl<-list()
for(i in 1:20)
  xl[[i]]<-crossprod(matrix(rnorm(1e6),1000,1000))
x<-xl
clusterExport(cl,"x",environment())
f0<-function(z) eigen(x[[z]])
system.time(clusterApply(cl,1:20,f0))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   0.332   0.264   3.334
```

Now, to make sure nothing weird is going on, restart R, and now run this similar code, which calls `clusterApply` from inside a function:

```
require(parallel)
cl<-makeCluster(rep("localhost",20),"SOCK")
xl<-list()
for(i in 1:20)
  xl[[i]]<-crossprod(matrix(rnorm(1e6),1000,1000))
f<-function(clust,x){
  force(x)
  clusterExport(clust,"x",environment())
  f0<-function(z) eigen(x[[z]])
  print(system.time(clusterApply(clust,1:20,f0)))
}
f(cl,xl)
##   user  system elapsed 
##  5.212   1.888  13.627
```

I did some searching and found [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037825/2588184), which points out that local variables used in functions which are not defined in the global environment are exported to the cluster.  So I thought, maybe the problem is that `x` is getting exported twice, and that's what's taking a long time, not the actual function call.  To test this I changed the function definition to:

```
f0<-function(z) eigen(get("x")[[z]])
```

and I still got the slow performance.  Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Incidentally, if I just call

```
clusterApply(clust,x,eigen)
```

inside the function, then it works fine, just as fast as if it were in the global environment.  And of course, if this were the problem I'm trying to solve, I'd simply do that, but it's not, this is just a toy problem to isolate the issue I'm having with other more complicated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your performance is indeed hurt because the variable `x` is being sent along with the `f0` function in every task.  Changing the way that `f0` refers to `x` makes no difference: the problem has nothing to do with how `f0` uses `x` or whether it refers to `x` at all.  It has to do with where `f0` itself is defined.  If you defined it outside of `f` such that the associated environment of `f0` was the global environment, then your problem would be fixed.

If you want to define `f0` inside `f`, you can fix it by modifying the environment of `f0` after you've defined it:

```
f<-function(clust,x){
  force(x)
  clusterExport(clust,"x",environment())
  f0<-function(z) eigen(x[[z]])
  environment(f0) <- .GlobalEnv
  print(system.time(clusterApply(clust,1:20,f0)))
}
```

This fixes the problem because the global environment is never serialized along with functions.

The reason that `clusterApply(clust,x,eigen)` works well is that `eigen` is not defined in `f`, so `x` is not captured when `eigen` is serialized.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation.  In retrospect, I guess this might be "obvious": instead of parsing the function to try and figure out what objects are being referred to, it's just going to export the whole associated environment.  But I'm pretty sure it would have taken me a long time to figure that out.