# Optimal way of multiprocessing a rowwise matching operation between two data frames

Tags: r, performance, multiprocessing, data.table

I'm working on an entity resolution task with large databases (`df1` ~0.5 mil. rows, `df2` up to 18 mil. rows).

In `df1` I have first and last names, with first names being in regex form to allow for multiple variations of the same name - I didn't bother including it in the attached example, but the string values look something like: `^(^robert$|^rob$|^robb$)$`).

In `df2` I have regular first and last names.

My approach is to go through `df1` row by row, note the last name and first name regex, then filter `df2` first for an exact last name match, then for the first name regex match.

This is simulated in the below code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

df1 <- data.table(id1=sprintf("A%s",1:10000),
                  fnreg1=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=10000,length=2,pattern="[a-z]"),
                  lname1=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=10000,length=2,pattern="[a-z]")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(fnreg1 = paste0("^(",fnreg1,")$"))

df2 <- data.table(id2=sprintf("B%s",1:100000),
                  fname2=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=100000,length=2,pattern="[a-z]"),
                  lname2=stringi::stri_rand_strings(n=100000,length=2,pattern="[a-z]"))


process_row <- function(i){
  
  rw <- df1[i,]
  
  fnreg <- rw$fnreg1
  ln <- rw$lname1
  
  ln.match <- df2[lname2==ln, ]
  out.match <- ln.match[grepl(fnreg, fname2), ]
  
  return(cbind(rw,out.match))
  
}

## 16 seconds
tictoc::tic()
out <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), process_row) %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% na.omit()
tictoc::toc()
```

The `lapply` format I want to keep for parallelizing. I use the following code, note I'm on Windows so I need to prepare the clusters to get it working:

```
library(parallel)
prep_cluster <- function(export_vars){
  
  cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(dplyr))
  clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))
  clusterExport(cl, export_vars)
  return(cl)
  
}

cl <- prep_cluster(list("df1","df2","process_row"))

## 2 seconds
tictoc::tic()
out.p <- parLapply(cl, 1:nrow(df1), process_row) %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% na.omit()
tictoc::toc()

stopCluster(cl)
```

For my large datasets, my code works pretty slowly. I'm almost certain that the way I defined `process_row` is very poorly optimized. But I'm not sure how to change the function to be faster and still conform to the `parLapply` format.

Any tips appreciated.

EDIT: I'm pretty short on memory, working with only 32GB - so I need to optimize it that way too.

For the largest data files (18 mil rows) I am splitting them into chunks and matching each chunk separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matchName1` and `parMatchName1` functions below are non-parallel and parallel solutions that avoid the cartesian join in langtang's answer and improve on its performance (both time and memory) by about an order of magnitude on very large `data.tables`.

The idea is to "collapse" then join the `data.tables` by last name, which avoids going cartesian (inspect the output of the `collapseName` function to see what I mean). `data.table` does this so efficiently that the vast majority of time is spent in `grepl`. There are certainly faster algorithms to perform the needed comparisons being performed by `grepl`, but I'm not aware of any package that offers essentially a vectorized `outer` version of `grepl`. If one exists, I wouldn't be surprised if it could speed up processing by another order of magnitude.

First, the functions:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
library(parallel)

vgrepi <- function(str, pattern) {
  # Searches for each value in "pattern" in each value in "str".
  # Returns a list of two equal-length vectors of (str, pattern) indices where
  # "pattern" is found in "str".
  # Accepts vectors for both "str" and "pattern".
  lall <- vector("list", length(pattern))
  for (i in seq_along(pattern)) lall[[i]] <- grep(pattern[i], str)
  list(rep.int(seq_along(pattern), lengths(lall)), unlist(lall))
}

collapseName <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  # collapse "dt1" and "dt2" by "lname1" and "lname2" then join on "lname1 =
  # lname2"
  dt1[
    , .(id1 = .(id1), fnreg1 = .(fnreg1)), lname1
  ][
    dt2[, .(id2 = .(id2), fname2 = .(fname2)), lname2],
    `:=`(id2 = i.id2, fname2 = i.fname2),
    on = .(lname1 = lname2)
  ]
}

getMatches <- function(dt) {
  # returns a data.table of full-name matches
  dt[
    , {
      idx <- vgrepi(fname2[[1]], fnreg1[[1]])
      
      if (length(idx[[1]])) {
        data.table(
          id1 = id1[[1]][idx[[1]]],
          fnreg1 = fnreg1[[1]][idx[[1]]],
          id2 = id2[[1]][idx[[2]]],
          fname2 = fname2[[1]][idx[[2]]]
        )
      } else NULL
    },
    lname1
  ]
}

matchName1 <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  setorder(getMatches(collapseName(dt1, dt2)), id1, id2)
}

parMatchName1 <- function(dt1, dt2, ncl = detectCores() - 1L) {
  # parallel version of matchName1
  cl <- makeCluster(ncl)
  on.exit(stopCluster(cl))
  dt3 <- collapseName(dt1, dt2)[
    # assign each row a node; attempt to balance by number of grepl comparisons
    , node := rep(c(1:ncl, ncl:1), ceiling(.N/ncl/2))[1:.N][rank(-lengths(fnreg1)*lengths(fname2), ties.method = "first")]
  ]
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(data.table); library(stringi)})
  idx <- 1:(ncol(dt3) - 1L)
  for (i in seq_along(cl)) {
    # pass only the needed portion of "dt3" to each node
    dt4 <- dt3[node == i, ..idx]
    clusterExport(cl[i], "dt4", environment())
  }
  rm("dt3", "dt4")
  clusterExport(cl, c("getMatches", "vgrepi"))
  # don't use parLapply as below--it is really slow for some reason
  # setorder(rbindlist(parLapply(cl, seq_along(cl), function(i) getMatches(dt4))), id1, id2)
  setorder(rbindlist(clusterEvalQ(cl, getMatches(dt4))), id1, id2)
}

matchName2 <- function(dt1, dt2) {
  # langtang's cartesian join solution (with sorting and column re-ordering to
  # match the output of "matchName1")
  setorder(dt1[dt2, on = .(lname1 = lname2), allow.cartesian = TRUE][, .SD[grepl(.BY, fname2)], fnreg1][, c(3:1, 4:5)], id1, id2)
}
```

Now the smaller example data:

```
# OP example data set
set.seed(1)
n1 <- 1e4
n2 <- 1e5
dt1 <- data.table(id1 = sprintf("A%s", 1:n1),
                  fnreg1 = paste0("^(", stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n1, length = 2, pattern = "[a-z]"), ")$"),
                  lname1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n1, length = 2, pattern = "[a-z]"))
dt2 <- data.table(id2 = sprintf("B%s", 1:n2),
                  fname2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n2, length = 2, pattern = "[a-z]"),
                  lname2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n2, length = 2, pattern = "[a-z]"))
```

And benchmarking:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(matchName1 = matchName1(dt1, dt2),
                               parMatchName1 = parMatchName1(dt1, dt2),
                               matchName2 = matchName2(dt1, dt2),
                               check = "equal",
                               times = 10L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>           expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#>     matchName1 202.9344 208.0844 237.0543 236.0003 265.3224  270.3858    10
#>  parMatchName1 756.9239 780.6850 859.9187 843.9129 887.5163 1103.2233    10
#>     matchName2 383.2535 417.7220 442.6772 435.9115 471.2729  537.4580    10
```

For the smaller data sets, the overhead involved in setting up parallel processing dominates the timings, but for much larger data sets, the parallel option gives a considerable speed boost.

```
# much larger test data set with 3-character names
set.seed(1)
n1 <- 5e5
n2 <- 18e6
dt1 <- data.table(id1 = sprintf("A%s", 1:n1),
                  fnreg1 = paste0("^(", stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n1, length = 3, pattern = "[a-z]"), ")$"),
                  lname1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n1, length = 3, pattern = "[a-z]"))
dt2 <- data.table(id2 = sprintf("B%s", 1:n2),
                  fname2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n2, length = 3, pattern = "[a-z]"),
                  lname2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = n2, length = 3, pattern = "[a-z]"))
```

Timings:

```
# set up matrix to store memory usage
memUsage <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(c("Ncels", "Vcells"), c("matchName1", "parMatchName1", "matchName2")))
invisible(gc(reset = TRUE))
system.time(matchName1(dt1, dt2))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   48.61    0.44   48.90
memUsage[, 1] <- gc()[,6]
invisible(gc(reset = TRUE))
system.time(parMatchName1(dt1, dt2))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    7.69    1.69   26.67
memUsage[, 2] <- gc()[,6]
invisible(gc(reset = TRUE))
system.time(matchName2(dt1, dt2))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  205.13   51.36  255.99
memUsage[, 3] <- gc()[,6]
```

Memory usage (in MBs):

```
memUsage
#>        matchName1 parMatchName1 matchName2
#> Ncels      1311.8        1100.5     1846.9
#> Vcells     1792.3        1325.9    26659.9
```

Comment: Probable reason behind the terrible `parLapply` performance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471742/9463489

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this solution. I managed to get by with the cartesian joins for now but I'll definitely check it out and implement when refactoring

Answer (score 2):

My apologies if this strays from your row-by-row processing approach too much, but have you tried simply joining on last name (allowing cartesian), and then just doing the regex match by `fnreg1`?

```
df1[df2, on=.(lname1=lname2), allow.cartesian=T][, .SD[grepl(.BY,fname2)], fnreg1]
```

Gives the same output as `out` much more quickly (on my machine about 15 times faster)

```
      fnreg1   id1 lname1    id2 fname2
   1: ^(zz)$  A922     oh B99195     zz
   2: ^(gc)$ A9092     tw  B8522     gc
   3: ^(gc)$ A9092     tw B31522     gc
   4: ^(qr)$ A3146     eo B57772     qr
   5: ^(qr)$ A8466     fo B62764     qr
  ---                                  
2119: ^(da)$ A8238     nl  B2678     da
2120: ^(da)$ A3858     bd B14722     da
2121: ^(da)$ A9325     cr B86598     da
2122: ^(da)$ A9325     cr B98444     da
2123: ^(mf)$ A1109     aq B43220     mf
```

If the `allow.cartesian` approach is too much here, we could potentially parallelize on unique first name regex, or on the unique lastnames

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel()
```

1. on regex:

```
foreach(fnreg= unique(df1$fnreg1), .packages = c("data.table"),.combine="rbind") %dopar% {
  df1[fnreg1==fnreg][df2[grepl(fnreg,fname2)], on=.(lname1=lname2), nomatch=0]
}
```

2. on lastname

```
foreach(ln= unique(df1$lname1), .packages = c("data.table"),.combine="rbind") %dopar% {
  df1[lname1==ln][df2[lname2==ln], on=.(lname1=lname2), allow.cartesian=T, nomatch=0][, .SD[grepl(.BY,fname2)], fnreg1]
}
```

Both provide the same output

Comment: I like the thought, but *"df2 up to 18 mil. rows"* and a cartesian join to me sounds likely to produce memory-exhaustion. I'm tired just thinking of it ;-)

Comment: yes, but it is limited by the lastname match. that helps a lot

Comment: In *this* sample data, while the max number of occurrences of a single last name is 26 in `df1` and 191 in `df2`, the resulting expansion ranges from 5x number of rows (best-case) to 26x (worst-case). I think a *crawling* mechanism (e.g., `for` loop?) would not exhaust memory, but a simple join is still likely to do so. I think, though, that your suggestion here is very similar to my premise of pre-splitting the frames and only merging one last-name at a time (regardless of the merge methods), great minds :-)

Comment: all good points @r2evans.. My initial splitting approach would have been on the regexs.. See my edit, with possible parallel approach

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question to reflect that I am short on memory with these large datasets.

Will test your solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelizing it is a little problematic: in order to do a true match, each process needs all rows, otherwise your join will invariably be incomplete. With large data, you're going to run into problems with passing the data back and forth. This type of join is what the `fuzzyjoin` package was written to solve:

```r
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_inner_join(
  df1, df2, by = c("lname1"="lname2", "fnreg1"="fname2"),
  match_fun = list(`==`, Vectorize(grepl)))
```

This produces effectively the same output but takes 2-3x as long, most likely because it is more general than your function.

Here's a suggestion, though, that allows parallelization of it in a safer manner: pre-`split` on the last name, parallelize for each last name (or batch of last names), and then join them in the end. Effectively:

```r
df1spl <- split(df1, df1$lname1)
df2spl <- split(df2, df2$lname2)
allnms <- sort(unique(c(names(df1spl), names(df2spl))))
head(allnms)
# [1] "aa" "ab" "ac" "ad" "ae" "af"
```

At this point, each of the `*spl` is a named list with frames, where each frame has a homogenous `lname*` column (intentional). I use `allnms` here to ensure that the names all match and in the same order, so for instance `names(df1spl)` may not be the same as `names(df2spl)`, but `names(df1spl[allnms])` will have the same length and order of names as `names(df2spl[allnms])`. From here, I'll demo with `Map` but you should be able to employ the parallel version with `clusterMap`:

```r
system.time(
  out3 <- Map(function(a, b) fuzzyjoin::regex_inner_join(a, b, by = c(fnreg1="fname2")),
              df1spl[allnms], df2spl[allnms])
)
# df1spl[[1]]
#    user  system elapsed 
#   30.64    1.27   32.04
```

And the results should be the same:

```r
out3 <- rbindlist(out3)
out3
#          id1 fnreg1 lname1    id2 fname2 lname2
#       <char> <char> <char> <char> <char> <char>
#    1:  A4196 ^(gb)$     aa B52781     gb     aa
#    2:  A7253 ^(sg)$     aa B91012     sg     aa
#    3:  A4675 ^(pe)$     ab B22248     pe     ab
#    4:  A7179 ^(is)$     ac B33418     is     ac
#    5:  A7158 ^(fn)$     ae B77991     fn     ae
#    6:  A6220 ^(kd)$     af B66989     kd     af
#    7:  A5950 ^(wv)$     ag B58928     wv     ag
#    8:  A6502 ^(jm)$     ag  B2949     jm     ag
#    9:   A515 ^(is)$     ai B36747     is     ai
#   10:  A4129 ^(np)$     ai B34729     np     ai
#   ---                                          
# 2114:  A8396 ^(pm)$     zv B26980     pm     zv
# 2115:  A1039 ^(ym)$     zw B60065     ym     zw
# 2116:  A6119 ^(hl)$     zw B71474     hl     zw
# 2117:  A9173 ^(ke)$     zw  B9806     ke     zw
# 2118:  A9847 ^(zn)$     zw  B9835     zn     zw
# 2119:  A5850 ^(nd)$     zx B92629     nd     zx
# 2120:  A5736 ^(ty)$     zy B89244     ty     zy
# 2121:  A7197 ^(yx)$     zz   B657     yx     zz
# 2122:  A9115 ^(fv)$     zz B83779     fv     zz
# 2123:  A9121 ^(ss)$     zz B23468     ss     zz

identical(out[order(id1,lname1,fname2),], out3[order(id1,lname1,fname2),])
# [1] TRUE
```

Having gone through all of that, it is feasible that you can take your bespoke function and use that instead of `fuzzyjoin`, with no more need to pre-match on `lname*`. Since your function is faster here than `fuzzyjoin`, you may benefit a bit more.

I should note that the use of `split(.)` will, by definition, duplicate your data in memory. If you are short on RAM, then you might need to be careful in how you do this.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the question to reflect that I am indeed short on memory.

The fuzzyjoin I tried a while ago and gave up due to memory issues.

Will try implementing your approach soon.